# How to automatically set hspace to inline 2nd column?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, inline

I'm new to latex and i wonder how to create a table-like look, because now i have to set the hspace manually to get my expected result.
How can i line up a "second column" on top of each other?

**How i actually do it manually:**

```
Elongation: \hspace{24pt} $y(t) = r * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0)$\\
Geschwindigkeit: \hspace{1pt} $v(t) = r * \omega * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = y'(t)$\\
Beschleunigung: \hspace{5pt} $a(t) = r * \omega^2 * -\sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = v'(t) = y''(t)$\\\\
```

**Should look like this:**

```
Elongation:       y(t) = r∗sin(ω∗t + φ0)
Geschwindigkeit:  v(t) = r∗ω∗sin(ω∗t + φ0) = y0(t)
Beschleunigung:   a(t) = r∗ω2 ∗−sin(ω∗t + φ0) = v0(t) = y00(t)
```

Comment: The asterisk in mathematics (as opposed to computer programming languages) doesn't mean multiplication, generally. The first formula is traditionally written `$y(t)=r\sin(\omega t+\phi_{0})$`

Comment: I know but i don't really like how it looks like with no space between 2 variables, so i need to set anything between.

Comment: I read that "\cdot" is often used for that purpose. I'm gonna try this variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table-like? Why not just the traditional `tabular`?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{parskip,array}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}\tabcolsep0pt
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}l}
Elongation:      & $y(t) = r * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0)$\\
Geschwindigkeit: & $v(t) = r * \omega * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = y'(t)$\\
Beschleunigung:  & $a(t) = r * \omega^2 * -\sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = v'(t) = y''(t)$\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For long formulas, just use a table with two  `p{<width>}` columns  (or environments like `tabular*`, `tabularx` or `tabulary`).

OK, ok, ... without tabular, just simpler with `tabto`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabto,parskip}
\NumTabs{4}
\begin{document}
Elongation:     \tab $y(t) = r * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0)$\par
Geschwindigkeit:\tab $v(t) = r * \omega * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = y'(t)$\par
Beschleunigung: \tab $a(t) = r * \omega^2 * -\sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = v'(t) = y''(t)$ 
\end{document}
```

For long formulas, you can use some like  `\tab\parbox[t]{.7\linewidth}{$...$}`. If you need custom Tab positions, use some like 
`\TabPositions{0pt, 0.3\linewidth}` instead of  `\NumTabs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain this with a `description` environment, using convenient parameters:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{1em}
\newlength{\descrwidth}

\begin{document}

{\settowidth{\descrwidth}{Geschwindigkeit:\quad}
\begin{description}[font=\normalfont, noitemsep, labelwidth=\dimexpr\descrwidth, leftmargin =\descrwidth, labelsep=0pt]
\item[Elongation:]$y(t) = r * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0)$ Text text text. Text text text. Text text text. Text text text. \\
\item[Geschwindigkeit:] $v(t) = r * \omega * \sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = y'(t)$\\
\item[Beschleunigung:] $a(t) = r * \omega^2 * -\sin(\omega*t+\phi_0) = v'(t) = y''(t)$\\\\
\end{description}}

\end{document}
```

[image]